# Developer tools console logs 3 for a=3 and undefined for var a = 3

Tags: javascript, developer-tools

In chrome Developer tools, when I type
    *a = 3* logs *3* but 
    *var a = 3* logs *undefined*.

Why does the first statement return 3 but not the second one?

Comment: `a = 3` is an expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because that's the way it is.

A statement beginning `var` is a declaration. Declarations don't, in and of themselves, have a value. They tell the computer to do something (to create a variable, optionally with some initial value).

But assignment expressions are different. `a = b` evaluates to (or "has") the new value of `a`, in order to allow chaining, such as `a = b = c = d`.

Could they have made it so that `var a = b` was an expression and evaluated to something? Sure, probably. But it would hold absolutely no useful value to butcher the language grammar in such a manner.

Read up about *statements* and *expressions* in programming languages.

Answer (score 3):

Because `undefined` is the result of the `var` statement.

Statements don't actually have a "result" that can be used in your code, but a program has a final result, and your single line of code in the console is evaluated as a program.

Comment: Don't confuse evaluation and execution.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Well, it's "evaluated" in the sense that `eval` "evaluates" a snippet of code and provides its result. The code is evaluated as a full program, not necessarily a single expression.

Comment: While a C or C++ program returns a value to the surrounding environment, that is not true of JavaScript in a browser. What is the value that is the result of the program? There isn't one. Similarly, referring to your comment on Rishikesh's answer, you said `var a = 3` "is definitely evaluated" but given that it has no value that is obviously not the case.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It does have a value, just not one that can be accessed as a value within the program, unless `eval` was used to execute it within the program. For example: `var x = eval("for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {i}"); console.log(x); // 9`

Comment: That's a [completion value](http://www.mattzeunert.com/2017/01/10/whats-a-statement-completion-value-in-javascript.html). It's not "the result of the program"; it's the value of the last evaluated expression within said program. Cherry-picking a program with only one expression is cheating!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Hence the distinctions I've made. In my other comment, the code is evaluated just as `eval` would and provides the resulting value to the console. To say it isn't evaluated would be incorrect, and would imply that there is now no `a` variable.

Comment: Not sure what I can add over what I've already said.

Comment: ...oh goodness, "result of the program" is an informal way of referring to the completion value. A program spits out a final result. That result is a potentially usable value to whatever executed the program.

Comment: So now we're changing the meaning of words to fit our desired conclusions.. noted! Have a nice day Zach

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: No, I'm only using informal terminology. We do it every day. Not all communication needs to be perfectly formal.

Comment: The program I showed above ends with a `for` statement, yet it provides a result value. It's not cheating. That's silly. The value of the result is that which is provided by the last statement, so anything before it becomes irrelevant. It's not cherry-picking; it's providing a simple example that demonstrates the point.